# Azure Log Analytics - IIS Log (W3CIISLog) Not Captured

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

We have installed the Microsoft Monitoring Agent on window server to capture IIS Logs; at the OMS Data Settings have enabled the "Collect W3C format IIS log files".

But at the Log Analytics cannot seeing any IIS logs is appear. Any idea on this.

Comment: Have you checked the blog: [Monitoring IIS Webserver in OMS](https://mykloud.wordpress.com/2017/04/09/monitoring-iis-webserver-in-oms/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was just a delay - by default Azure collects IIS logs only once per day (when log file is closed). It depends on  **Log File Rollover Schedule** setting - you can change it in logging tab in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Monitor collects IIS log entries from each agent each time the log is closed and a new one is created. This frequency is controlled by the Log File Rollover Schedule setting for the IIS site which is once a day by default. For example, if the settings is Hourly, then Azure Monitor will collect the log each hour. If the setting is Daily, then Azure Monitor will collect the log every 24 hours.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-iis-logs).